# Сделать монохромное тепловизионное изображение разноцветным

Tags: алгоритм, изображения

Вопрос. Нужно монохромное тепловизионное изображение сделать разноцветным с помощью Matlab. Каким образом можно это реализовать, зная только диапазон температур? Как составить алгоритм?

Comment: 1. А причём тут температура? Температура чего?
2. Если речь идёт об _алгоритме_, матлаб тут не при чём.

Comment: Диапазон температур нужен что-бы на изображении точно было видно разность температур (термограмма человеческого тела). Я сама в матлабе не работала ни разу. И на сколько знаю, каждая программа имеет алгоритм. Хочу спросить у знающих людей. Может кто-то занимался чем-то подобным.

Comment: @Nastya_Ju: А откуда берётся температура? Она как-то связана с исходной чёрно-белой картинкой?

Утверждение о том, что каждая программа имеет алгоритм, лучше не комментировать.

Comment: Наобум. минимум - температура окружающей среды в норме (примерно 20-22 гр), максимум - максимум температуры кожи на поверхности (с округлением около 37). В исходном варианте у нас только RGB картинка (и все три составляющие одинаковые) от 0 до 248. И на сколько я понимаю нужно разделить этот диапазон на промежутки, и окрашивать в свой цвет. Может что-то вроде водораздела. Хотя там только линия рисуется вроде. В общем нужно придумать как соотнести серость с цветом. А температура это вообще уже наверное больше для эмпирического восприятия.

Comment: @Nastya_Ju: попробуйте сами прочитать свой вопрос. Не понятно **вообще** ничего. Какая связь температуры и картинки? Причём тут кожа на поверхности? На картинке изображён человек? Из вас детали приходится тянуть клещами.

Comment: Изображение сделано термографом (или тепловизором), чувствительность 0.02 гр на 1 бит. Изображен человек. Нужно монохромное изображение сделать цветным. Какие детали нужны вам я не знаю. Никакой информации об аппарате нет.

Comment: @VladD, я попробую немного поизображать из себя Вангу и формализовать своё видение этой задачи. Есть монохромная картинка. Есть маппинги диапазонов яркости на цвета, например,

    [0...100] -> RGB(0,0,255)
    [100...200] -> RGB(0,255,0)
    [200...255] -> RGB(255,0,0)

Задача - преобразовать цвета пикселей картинки в соответствии с маппингом.

@Nastya_Ju, читайте про [язык Матлаба][1] в общем, и про функции [`imread` и `imwrite`][2] в частности.

  [1]: http://vk.com/doc895377_138747262?hash=1f04f9cdff152660a4&dl=28aabb49a7217e1962
  [2]: http://sernam.ru/lect_matlab.php?id=23

Comment: @fori1ton: интерпретация имеет право на существование. В такой постановке алгоритм тривиален: применение маппинга _n_ раз.

Comment: ))) Я пробовала так: задавая условие диапазона, менять каждую из RGB компонент. И так несколько диапазонов с разными значениями компонет. Но выходил только один цвет, только красный, но разных оттенков или только зелены. И это с помощью логических операций: if, else, or... и т.д. Но может это возможно осуществить математическими методами?

Comment: [Разглядывание картинок](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) наводит на мысль, что маппинг, предложенный @fori1ton, не очень подходит.

Более естественные изображения получаются, если выбросить один из чистых цветов (например, зеленый).

--

Тогда переход от минимальной температуры (черный, 0) к максимальной (белый, 248) проходит от темно синего до чисто синего, затем добавляем красный и убираем синий до чисто красного, потом добавляем зеленый до желтого,  а потом начинаем добавлять синий (до белого).

--

места мало...

Comment: Разные чистые цвета с одинаковой "числовой" яркостью в RGB (например, 255.0.0 и 0.0.255) воспринимаются глазом, как будто у них разная яркость. Самый яркий - зеленый, а самый тусклый синий. 

В вашем случае, чем больше температура, тем ярче должен выглядеть цвет.

Кое что на эту тему есть в статьях [гамма-коррекция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) 
 и [RGB](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB).

Вообще-то была в X-Windows простая формула `Briteness = Nr * R + Ng * G + Nb * B`, но значения Nr, Ng и Nb не помню...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Допустим мы умеем на основании черно-белой картинки сопоставлять значение яркости с температурой. Если известен только диапазон температур то можно предполагать линейную зависимость между температурой и яркостью.
2. Теперь берем значение яркости/температуры и строим цветовую модель [HSV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)) (hue-saturation-value), где нашу яркость из черно-белой картинки сопоставляем с компонентой Hue (цветность). Самая высокое значение температуры принимаем за красный цвет (hue=0), самое низкую температуру за темно-синий (hue=270)
3. Задаемся некими фиксированными значениями S - насыщенности цвета и V - яркости)
4. Формируем полный цвет по модели HSV (при необходимости переводя его в RGB пространство).

Comment: Следуя вашей логике, этот вариант мне нравится. Попробую как-нибудь теперь реализовать на деле. Спасибо.

Comment: @Nastya_Ju, вот с запозданием пришло в голову чисто практическое решение (правда, не знаю, можно ли это реализовать в Matlab).

Надо найти картинку с подходящей цветной шкалой температур. Разбить ее на N частей (в соответствии с градациями серого в Ваших изображениях) и из какого-либо пиксела каждой части взять RGB. 

Ну, и составить табличку (индекс -- градация серого) и забить ее в программу.

Answer (score 4):

Вот, нашел [подходящее обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

```
Luminance (standard, objective): (0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B)
Luminance (perceived option 1): (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B)
Luminance (perceived option 2, slower to calculate): sqrt( 0.241*R^2 + 0.691*G^2 + 0.068*B^2 )
```